# Two products in first line in prestashop, then three

Tags: php, html, css, prestashop

I am building shop in prestashop. On my main page I have products lists and it looks like:

x = product

```
X X X 

X X X
```

But I want to change it to

```
X X 

X X X 

X X X
```

When I do nth-child on first element it works, but then it looks like

```
X X 

X

XXX
```

So it can't be like this. How can I reach this?

Code:

```
<ul id="products">
   <li class="product"><div>DESCRIPTION HERE</div><li>
  <li class="product"><div>DESCRIPTION HERE</div><li>
  <li class="product"><div>DESCRIPTION HERE</div><li>
  <li class="product"><div>DESCRIPTION HERE</div><li>
  <li class="product"><div>DESCRIPTION HERE</div><li>
</ul>
```

and:

```
.product:nth-child(1) {
    display: block;
    width: 50% !important;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you add a `margin-right` to the 2nd X? This way you would push the 3rd X to the 2nd row.

Comment: give us a complete code so we can correct you

Comment: my 3rd X is pushed to 2nd row, but here's alone. I need him to stick with other products

Comment: please include your code, are you using any frameworks?

Comment: add simple code. those code you write.

Comment: @Znaneswar update

Answer (score 0):

This is not exact answer because your code is not sufficient to answer your question but try like this.

try to append an empty `li` as 3rd element from JQuery/JS to solve your issue

```
//JQuery
 $(window).on('load', function() {
   $("#products:nth-child(3)").append("<li></li>");
 })
```

//Javascript

```
$(window).load(function(){ $("#products:nth-child(3)").append("<li></li>"); })
```

will give you

```
<ul id="products">
   <li class="product"><div>DESCRIPTION HERE</div><li>
   <li class="product"><div>DESCRIPTION HERE</div><li>
   <li><li>
   <li class="product"><div>DESCRIPTION HERE</div><li>
   <li class="product"><div>DESCRIPTION HERE</div><li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just to point out that while your solution may work, OP has not tagged this question `jquery`.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this a few ways, here is one using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
#products {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.product {
  list-style: none;
  width: 33%;
}

.product:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 66%;
}
```

```html
<ul id="products">
  <li class="product">
    <div>DESCRIPTION HERE</div>
  </li>
  <li class="product">
    <div>DESCRIPTION HERE</div>
  </li>
  <li class="product">
    <div>DESCRIPTION HERE</div>
  </li>
  <li class="product">
    <div>DESCRIPTION HERE</div>
  </li>
  <li class="product">
    <div>DESCRIPTION HERE</div>
  </li>
  <li class="product">
    <div>DESCRIPTION HERE</div>
  </li>
  <li class="product">
    <div>DESCRIPTION HERE</div>
  </li>
  <li class="product">
    <div>DESCRIPTION HERE</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```